# Can I display the current playing song title in an UILabel from a PLS Stream?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avplayer

Can I display the current playing song title in an `UILabel` from a `PLS Stream`?

Currently this is my Code:

.h Controller:

```
AVPlayer *music;
```

.m Controller:

```
NSString *u = @"http://sc7b.apple-fm.net:8188/listen.pls";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];
music = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
[music play];
```

Thank you in front :)

Comment: http://mobisoftinfotech.com/integrate-music-player-in-iphone/